# \ifx treats a control sequence differently if it is named using a \csname...\endcsname pair

Tags: tex-core, conditionals

Aren't the two expressions

```
\a
```

and

```
\csname a\endcsname
```

supposed to be equivalent?

Yet the following plain TeX manuscript

```
\ifx\a\relax yes\else no\fi\bye
```

outputs

> no

whereas the supposedly equivalent

```
\expandafter\ifx\csname a\endcsname\relax yes\else no\fi\bye
```

outputs

> yes

Comment: There are not equivalent, one of the differences is how undefined commands are handled. \a will give an error and \csname a\endcsname define the cs to \relax and insert this.

Comment: What Ulrike said!  Additionally, the cs version of the test is a convenient way to avoid errors if you wish to leave open the possibility that `\a` might be undefined going into the test.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes or to put it another way, `\csname` is a giant pit into which the unwary may fall, and it's convenient in that rare situation where you wish to trap bears in the middle of an innocuous looking document.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You have such a way with words.  I wish I had said that!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

they are equivalent to `\ifx`,

```
\ifx\a\relax yes\else no\fi



\expandafter\ifx\csname a\endcsname\relax yes\else no\fi


\ifx\a\relax yes\else no\fi

\bye
```

produces

> no yes yes

`\a` is yes if it is defined (and it gets defined by csname to be `\relax`) and no if it is not defined.

Answer (score 7):

The two constructs are not supposed to be equivalent.

Exercise 7.7 in the TeXbook (p. 40) says

> When `\csname` is used to define a control sequence for the first time, that control sequence is made equivalent to `\relax` until it is redefined.

If you compile

```
\tracingassigns=1
\expandafter\def\csname a\endcsname{whatever}
```

with an e-TeX enabled engine (`pdftex`, for instance), the log file will contain

```
{changing \a=undefined}
{into \a=\relax}
{changing \a=\relax}
{into \a=macro:->whatever}
```

which better explains the wording in the exercise.

Next we read on page 213

> - `\csname...\endcsname`. When TeX expands `\csname`
>     it reads to the matching `\endcsname`, expanding tokens as it goes;
>     only character tokens should remain after this expansion has taken place.
>     Then the “expansion” of the entire `\csname...\endcsname` text
>     will be a single control sequence token, defined to be like `\relax` if
>     its meaning is currently undefined.

This implies that

```
\expandafter\ifx\csname a\endcsname\relax
```

will return true unless `\a` was defined before the test to something whose meaning is not `\relax`.

To the contrary, if `\a` is not defined,

```
\begingroup\expandafter\endgroup
\expandafter\ifx\csname a\endcsname\relax
```

will return false, because `\endgroup` is executed before the conditional is tested, but after `\a` has been built from `\csname a\endcsname`; the end of the group will remove the previously assigned meaning to `\a`. However, this construct is not expandable: for instance,

```
\edef\x{\begingroup\expandafter\endgroup\expandafter\ifx\csname a\endcsname\relax true\else false\fi}
```

will make `\x` expand to `\begingroup\endgroup true`, because `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` are not executed during `\edef`.

This is the main reason why `\ifcsname` was added to e-TeX: when `\ifcsname...\endcsname` is performed, the constructed token will not be made equivalent to `\relax`.

Comment: Thanks. Why aren't `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` executed during `\edef`? How does `\edef` handle them, then?

Comment: @EvanAad It does nothing to them; during `\edef` only expansion up to unexpandable tokens is carried out.

Comment: I see. What did you mean by "an e-TeX enabled engine (`pdftex`, for instance)"? Isn't e-TeX a LaTeX package? Did you mean that the `etex.sty` is written in plain TeX and that it is implicitly `#include`ed in the beginning of every TeX manuscript that is processed with `pdftex`?

Comment: @EvanAad `texdoc etex` will explain more.

Comment: You [wrote](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/386490/ifx-treats-a-control-sequence-differently-if-it-is-named-using-a-csname-end/386499#comment957803_386499) that "during `\edef` only expansion up to unexpandable tokens is carried out." How do you define 'unexpandable token'? Is 'an unexpandable token' = 'a token that is not a macro'? Why is `\begingroup` an unexpandable token, whereas `\let` is an expandable token?

Comment: What makes you think that `\let` is an expandable token? It isn't: no assignment command is expandable.

Comment: If `\let` is not expandable, why do I often see the idiom `\edef\a{\noexpand\let...}`? What's the use of `\noexpand` if `\let` is not expandable?

Comment: @EvanAad The `\noexpand` there has no use; probably you refer to `\edef\a{\let\noexpand\foo...}` where we don't want `\foo` to expand (if expandable).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63950/discussion-between-evan-aad-and-egreg).